# Is there a C# direct2d or SharpDX equivalent to PathGradient brush?

Tags: c#, c, sharpdx, direct2d

Microsoft provided a PathGradient brush in the C programming language.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-creating-a-path-gradient-use

Note that this is not a linear gradient; you can specify the points at which the color shifts.

I have been unable to find an equivalent technique in C# and SharpDX.  Is there one?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.pathgradientbrush?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: That appears to be a linear brush.  I am interested in a method similar to a heat map.

Comment: The directx way is to use a *shader*.  GPUs really like them.  Play with [this sample](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/Direct3D12/HelloBundles) for example.